# python numpy generic axis notation

Tags: python, numpy

I am defining a numpy function that performs an action along a specified axis of the numpy array (more specifically, swapping a certain proportion of columns).

I am looking for a more generic approach to specifying the axis in the function instead of performing if / else branch:

```
def permute_rand(values, percent=.2, axis=0):

    size = values.shape[axis]
    to_permute = np.random.rand(size)<percent
    nb_perm = to_permute.sum()

    if axis == 0:
        values[to_permute,:] = values[to_permute,:][np.random.permutation(nb_perm),:]
    elif axis == 1:
        values[:,to_permute] = values[:,to_permute][:,np.random.permutation(nb_perm)]

    return values
```

Is there a more generic approach that would allow to specify a generic axis and perform the swap along that axis (provided the values is of sufficient dimension)?

Comment: Just as a vague idea, you could use `transpose` or `swapaxes` to swap axis 0 with the axis you want to operate on, do the permutation on axis 0, then swap again.

Comment: Another idea is to construct an indexing tuple, with the needed indices, None, and `slice` objects.  This is used in a number of nunpy functions.  But so is the idea of moving the operational axis to a known spot (end or start)